# Get next image from an album using Graph API

Tags: php, image, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am getting an image using it´s id but I also want to get the previous and next picture from the album.

Is there any way to do that using the graph API?

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need to get **all** the photos from the album and the manually sort in the order you want (Facebook doesn't allow you to sort by "created", which is probably what you want).

I find this is easier using FQL and example code is

```
SELECT pid FROM photo WHERE aid="20531316728_324257"
```

Details: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/photo/ (Note: you use the album ID for this call) but you can also do the equivalent in graph API - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/  (Note: you use the album's object ID for this call).